# Remove <script> and other tags with php

Tags: php

For a small one page CMS I want to replace `script` and other tags that people could use for bad intentions.

I've tried out [`strip_tags`](http://de3.php.net/strip-tags) and [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php) but it's not working for some reason.

The one page CMS has 6 fields to edit. Those are saved in a plain text file.
When I edit one of those, I need it to remove all tags like `script`, `embed`, `object`, `<iframe>` and others.

I've checked out [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org), but I don't get it how this should work as I'm not well known with php. Looks a bit too big for my needs I guess.

This is the code (here I try to remove tags from the `script` tag from text area named `newscontent`):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['edit'])) {

    $newscontent = preg_replace('/<script.+?<\/script>/im', '', $newscontent);

    if (file_put_contents('title.txt',          utf8_encode($_POST['title']))       !== FALSE &&
        file_put_contents('subtitle.txt',       utf8_encode($_POST['subtitle']))    !== FALSE &&
        file_put_contents('datum.txt',          utf8_encode($_POST['datum']))       !== FALSE &&
        file_put_contents('time.txt',           utf8_encode($_POST['time']))        !== FALSE &&
        file_put_contents('timemin.txt',        utf8_encode($_POST['timemin']))     !== FALSE &&
        file_put_contents('newscontent.txt',    utf8_encode($_POST['newscontent'])) !== FALSE
    )
        echo '<p class="succes">Your changes are saved</p>', "\n";
}
$title          = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('title.txt'));
$subtitle       = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('subtitle.txt'));
$datum          = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('datum.txt'));
$time           = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('time.txt'));
$timemin        = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('timemin.txt'));
$newscontent    = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('newscontent.txt'));
?>
```

Comment: Hand-crafted workarounds aren't advisable here. If security is the objective, then use a proven tool to accomplish it. And that's HTMLPurifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are performing the replacement on the variable `$newscontent`, but writing `$_POST['newscontent']` to the file. I guess you have register globals switched on (which is bad) or this would generate an error.

I would recommend you persevere with HTMLPurifier. There are many, many bad things people could add to text if they have 'bad intentions', and your approach does not even scratch the surface. For example, if you were to fix your code, it doesn't prevent people adding something like this:

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/logo.gif" onload="javascript:bad stuff here" />
```

not to mention the complications of different character sets.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to use HTMLPurifier, but for some reason I get the following error:
`Warning: Directory /.../DefinitionCache/Serializer not writable, please chmod to 777 in /Library/.../DefinitionCache/Serializer.php on line 179`

I edited the file with Finder to make it readable & editable for everybody, but it won't change.

this is how the code looks like now:
`<?php
require_once 'htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
 
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($_POST['newscontent']);
?>`

Comment: is `/.../DefinitionCache/Serializer` a valid path? 'Serializer' should be a folder, not a file. Once you've fixed that it should work as long as `$clean_html` is what you write to the file. If you're still having trouble it might be worth opening a new question about this.

Comment: I rechecked the files and saw the permissions were put back for some reason. Fixed it and no errors anymore.

But now it isn't changing this code insertion `<script>alert(1);</script>` Or is that because it can't do anything bad?

Comment: `<script>alert(1);</script>` should be escaped. It might be worth putting your updated code into a new question, but as I said before, make sure the variable you are escaping is the one you then write to the file

Answer (score -1):

< is a special character in regex, you need to escape it.

```
    $newscontent = preg_replace('/\<(script|object|embed).+?\<\/\1\>/im', '', $newscontent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm not going to use because I guess HTML Purifier is better to block most bad things that could happen.

But I've got your code working like this:
`$ersetzungen = array();
  $ersetzungen[2] = '/<img[^>]+\>/i';
  $ersetzungen[1] = '/\<(script|object|embed).+?\<\/\1\>/im';
  
  $_POST['title'] = preg_replace( $ersetzungen, '', $_POST['title']);
  $_POST['subtitle'] = preg_replace( $ersetzungen, '', $_POST['subtitle']);
  $_POST['datum'] = preg_replace( $ersetzungen, '', $_POST['datum']);
  $_POST['newscontent'] = preg_replace( $ersetzungen, '', $_POST['newscontent']);`

Comment: I agree 100% with that statement. Was just pointing out the piece of your code that was broken. :)