# Remove script tags using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

The title may not be very clear but I will clearly explain my problem here.

I am designing a website for my institute in which I had to provide a editor where user can create html pages and save them to certain folder (user wouldn't know the exact folder, it's created using php while registration). I have decided to use ck-editor for the editor purpose. To save the data I send a post request using ajax to a php script which simply uses

> file_put_contents("folder/file_name.html",$_POST['data'])

To show the pages view_page.php accepts the file name as a get variable and then includes the html file e.g.

URL:

> view_post.php?file_path=user/good.html

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    try{
        @include_once("ed423eba62af16d6ab38cbfd2295b304/".$_GET['file_name']);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Can't find the requested file.";
    }
?>
```

Now the problem I am facing is that if user submits data that contains some script tags I have to make sure that the script tags doesn't get saved or doesn't run when the page loads. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should contain no JS.

Comment: [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is currently the most complete solution to this problem.

Comment: I am checking HTML Purifier...

Comment: @kapa Hey thanks, HTML purifier looks good. I think it will do the job for me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove <script> and other tags with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021434/remove-script-and-other-tags-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `strip_tags()` - http://www.php.net/strip_tags or HTML Purifier - http://htmlpurifier.org/

I would suggest HTML Purifier.

Comment: +1 for HTML Purifier, but I would remove `strip_tags`, it gives the false feeling of security, should not be recommended.